# How to get address of an element in C++ string as array

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie in C++. I'm learning string and want to get the element's address in the string. I want to access data as an array in C. I tried to implement the code as below. The function getAddress_type1 worked as I expected, but function 2 is not. So what is different between these functions?

Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
char *getAddress_type1(string &str)
{
    char* dat = &str[0];
    return dat;
}

char *getAddress_type2(string *str)
{
    char* dat = (char *)str;
    return dat;
}

int main()
{
    //cout<<"Hello World" << "\r\n";
    string str1 = "Tesssst";
    char *ptr1 = getAddress_type1(str1);
    char *ptr2 = getAddress_type2(&str1);
    cout << ptr1[0] << "\r\n"; // output is T
    cout << ptr2[0] << "\r\n"; // output is 8
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe a string is just a class with two pointers of begin and end (correct me if I'm wrong though). To get the starting address of the actual string, use `begin()`. Or just use `c_str()` to get a C string.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is "never C-style cast to a pointer or reference".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to get to the underlying "C" array in a C++ string:

```
const char* dat = str.c_str();
```

This will not work:

```
char *getAddress_type2(string *str)
{
    char* dat = (char *)str;
    return dat;
}
```

A pointer to a C++ string is not a pointer to a `char`.  The cast isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your functions is that the first one takes its argument by reference, and the second one - by pointer. Internally (after the program has been compiled) both methods are practically equivalent, but on the source code level the difference is fundamental: pointers require special syntax (operator `.`, `->`, `*`, etc.). In your case:

```
char* getAddress_type2(string *str)
{
    char* dat = &(*str)[0];
    return dat;
}
```

or, if you can afford for a little `const` (that is, if you don't want to modify the contents of the string via the pointer):

```
const char* getAddress_type2(string *str)
{
    char* dat = str->c_str();
    return dat;
}
```

or simply

```
const char* getAddress_type2(string *str)
{
    return str->c_str();
}
```

The last two forms suggest adding some `const` to the type of the function argument:

```
const char* getAddress_type2(const string *str)
{
    return str->c_str();
}
```

See: [Wikibooks: C](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays) and [Wikibooks: C++](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Operators/Pointers), and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

Comment: `c_str()` returns a `const char *`, not a `char *`.

Comment: @mch You're right. I've edited the answer.